# Is it possible to de-serialize an XML document to XML document instead to an object file?

Tags: c#, xaml, xml-serialization, uwp-xaml, xml-deserialization

I have two different versions of XML files. First one being with lesser elements as it was developed earlier. now the newer version has extra elements. I am creating an app to detect the version of the xml document If the selected document is version0 (older version with less elements) then i need to add the new elements and create a new xml version (version1). so using serializer or deserializer for xaml or xml is the best approach or or is there any other way i can complete my task? I want to update the older xml files with new elements and save them as version1.

I am checking the version of the xml by running a for loop in the xml document as there is a child attribute which specifies the xml version.

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine: Deserialise using old format, then reserialise using new format.

Comment: Thank you mathew !! melody Zhou's Gave the perfect solution as well :) thanks for your time though !!

Comment: Hi @Faraazbhilwade, If the answer below can solve your problem, please mark it as an answer, which will help more people who have the same problem as you. :)

Comment: sure thing @richasy !!! i'll as soon as I m done with it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `XDocument`:

- using `System.Xml.Linq` namespace
- load file `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);`
- search special node(your version node)

```
var el = doc.Descendants("Version").Where(v => v.Attribute("version").Value =="0").FirstOrDefault();
if (el != null)
{
```

- update version attribute `el.SetAttributeValue("version", 1);`
- maybe you need delete some nodes

```
doc.Root.Remove(); //delete all nodes
doc.Descendants("NodeName").ToList().ForEach(xe => xe.Remove()); //delete nodename equals NodeName nodes
```

- add nodes

```
doc.Add(new XElement("...", new XAttribute("ID", 1)));//if you delete all nodes,you need add a root node
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("...", new XAttribute("ID", 1))); //add nodes
doc.Root.Element("...").Add(new XElement("...", new XAttribute("ID", 2)));  ////add nodes
```

- save file

```
doc.Save(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot melody !!

Comment: Hi melody, thanks for your help !! as I am new in XML - LINQ
I need to get the value from a specific attribute in my XML and save it in a public string ... I tried using descendants approach but my efforts are in vain !!!
I want to get the value "Biotest AG" from the attribute "Value" .... in the following XML:

Comment: you need  a  string  collection  from specific nodes or  need  the value from a specific node?

Comment: ```var list=doc.Descendants("nodeName").Select(node => node.Attribute("Value").Value).ToList();```if you need a  specific node attribute value,```Descendants(...).FirstOrDefault(n=>your filter)?.Select(...)```

Comment: Thank you !!! I worked it out this way `IEnumerable<string> CustomerName = from temp in doc.Descendants("Property").Where(v => v.Attribute("ID").Value == "S_Customer") select temp.Attribute("Value").Value;
            foreach (string item in CustomerName ) { result.S_Customer= item; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class to deserialize to for both the old and new version it shouldn't be a problem.

First deserialize the old XML to an object of the new class. Then you can set the new fields of the object and serialize it back to xml.

Comment: Thank you .. although melody's approach may solve my problem my real query was whether i can solve my task with serializer and deserializer or not .. from you response it seems i can ..!!